# Handling "stream buffering" and "stream interrupted" audio events

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-audio

I'm trying to build an audio player widget for a Vue.js-enabled website that can play live radio streams. I've gotten the basics of play/stop and audio source switching covered.

Now I'd like to hook into various playback events, mainly to

- Display a loading spinner while the **stream is buffering**
- Show some kind of error when the **stream is unwillingly interrupted** (due to network issues, server issues on the broadcaster's end, etc)

I've considered two approaches:

- **The low-level approach**: sticking with the standard `<audio>` tag and hooking in to [a big list of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to handle these cases to the best of my knowledge.
- **The high-level approach**: finding an existing JavaScript library or Vue.js component that takes the boilerplate out of this sort of work and provides an easier API to tap in to these events.

What's the best way to hook in to these events?